# Delayed Boot Time & Memory/RAM Issues

Tags: boot, memory, bios, desktop

I have an older Gateway GT5662, I'm having two specific issues that I think are related. I'll explain each separately and hopefully someone has come across this before.

*Break down of booting issue after pressing power button...*
**(1) First 5 seconds:** Sounds like it's booting up, fan starts to spin, power button light comes on. Then, it stops all the sudden. The power button light goes off temporarily.
**(2) Next 2-3 seconds:** The power button light comes back on, the fan starts to spin again, then it stops once again like it did the first time.
(2) then proceeds to happen ~8 times. After the 8th time, it boots up normally and works fine. It has **NEVER** failed to boot, but always goes through this process when booting.

*RAM/Memory Issue...*
I've ran numerous system tests on the machine to try to diagnose the booting problem myself, the only result that has been unfavorable from all these tests has been that the **first stick in my four memory/RAM slots** fails the following tests:
(1) Memory Isolation Test
(2) Microtopology Test

Again, to be clear, it's the *FIRST* memory/RAM stick in any of the four slots that fails the above tests. Therefore, if I had all four slots filled, the first slot's stick would fail the above tests. If I had the first slot empty and the other three slots filled, it would be the second slot's stick that fails the above tests. Yes, I've tried multiple RAM/Memory sticks, this makes me think it must be a software issue...

Please help! While the computer works fine for now, I use it for work since I can't afford a new one and am scared it will die on me soon.

**EDIT:**

Adding the memory tests that pass every time:
(1) Module Seating Test
(2) Inversion Tree Test
(3) Chaotic Addressing Test
(4) Block Rotation Test

**EDIT2:**

Adding some extra specs past the factory provided hardware:
(1) Radeon HD 6750 GPU
(2) Dynex 420W PSU
Everything else is default, factory provided with GT5662.

Comment: Sounds like it may be a lack of power, try a new PSU. Also, are there an expanded or damaged capacitors on the motherboard? (see: http://static.flickr.com/42/120329818_0e20370795_m.jpg for a reference to what I mean by expanded caps)

Comment: Definitely no damaged capacitors, that's one of the first things I looked for, I recently replaced the PSU since I added a new GPU that required a larger PSU. :(

Comment: Did this problem exist before you changed the GPU and PSU? If you try you old GPU and PSU does the problem continue?

Comment: Yes, it has been doing this for around a year or more. I had hoped like you that the new PSU might do it, but no such luck. Definitely no expanded caps after checking again to be sure.

Comment: I added some desktop specs to my question, after market hardware I replaced. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Regarding the multiple-boots to start: If you try to boot off a USB drive, or an optical disk, does it behave the same way?

Comment: Yes, it does. Since I have to get to the Gateway Welcome Screen to select the boot menu for optical or USB. When it finally finishes the boot sequence described in my post, it shows the welcome screen, but only after all the hesitations and what seem to be failed boot attempts. By the way, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: All of the hesitations last the exact same amount of time too, it seems like the computer is detecting an issue somewhere and maybe trying to reconfigure some settings over and over, before it finally gives up on the 8th try and boots.

Comment: might be dumb questions, but a) what happens if you remove all but one RAM stick & b) when it's fully loaded, what do you have 8 of? [or even 4]

Comment: I've confirmed that it isn't the RAM itself, and my post says what happens when it has only one stick left in or when all the slots are full, basically still acts the same way.